# Apex Class Validation Fails in TestSSDupeCatcherUtility

Tags: salesforce, apex, slack

I am using the following code (replaced Slack hook with placeholder) to post *Salesforce* opportunities on a *Slack* channel.

```apex
public with sharing class SlackOpportunityPublisher {

    private static final String slackURL = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/RESTOFWEBHOOKURL';

    public class Oppty {
        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Opportunity Name')
        public String opptyName;
        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Stage')
        public String stage;
    }

    @InvocableMethod(label = 'Post to Slack')
    public static void postToSlack(List<oppty> oppties) {
        Oppty o = oppties[0]; // If bulk, only post first to avoid overloading Slack channel
        Map<string, object> msg = new Map<string, object>();
        msg.put('text', 'The following opportunity has changed:\n' + o.opptyName + '\nNew Stage: *' + o.stage + '*');
        msg.put('mrkdwn', true);
        String body = JSON.serialize(msg);
        System.enqueueJob(new QueueableSlackCall(slackURL, 'POST', body));
    }

    public class QueueableSlackCall implements System.Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

        private final String url;
        private final String method;
        private final String body;

        public QueueableSlackCall(String url, String method, String body) {
            this.url = url;
            this.method = method;
            this.body = body;
        }

        public void execute(System.QueueableContext ctx) {
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(url);
            req.setMethod(method);
            req.setBody(body);
            Http http = new Http();
            if (!Test.isRunningTest()) { // HTTP callout is not allowed in tests apparently...
                HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

But when I want to validate this class, it fails with the following message. The error occurs in `TestSSDupeCatcherUtility` class and in the `testStaticResourceValRules` method.

> System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0  Stack Trace:
>   Class.SFSSDupeCatcher.SSDupeCatcherUtility.populateDefaultCustomFields:
>   line 382, column 1
>   Class.SFSSDupeCatcher.TestSSDupeCatcherUtility.testStaticResourceValRules:
>   line 56, column 1

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check `SFSSDupeCatcher` class the specified line in error message.

Comment: as Reshma mentioned the error is on `SFSSDupeCatcher` class and you need to check that. If you have any troubles with detection of error in this class then post `SFSSDupeCatcher` class here